# Auto layout, screen rotation and UIView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am having an issue with a UIView that I add to the the bottom of the screen and animate it up to fill most of the screen if a button is pressed. The view will animate up and down and rotates as intended. If I try to animate while in landscape, it breaks and gives me error message:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIScrollView _edgeExpressionInContainer:vertical:max:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:2174
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Autolayout doesn't support crossing rotational bounds transforms with edge layout constraints, such as right, left, top, bottom. The offending view is: <UIView: 0x9199340; frame = (20 0; 748 1024); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x91993d0>>'
```

The offending view is self.view.

How I create the UIView:

```
[self.myContentView addSubview:subBar.filterListView];

[self.myContentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[filterListView]|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:@{@"filterListView": subBar.filterListView}]];

subBar.filterListView.bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subBar.filterListView
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:self.mapView
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                     multiplier:1
                                                                       constant:0];

subBar.filterListView.topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subBar.filterListView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:self.mapView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                  multiplier:1
                                                                    constant:0];

[self.myContentView addConstraint:subBar.filterListView.bottomConstraint];
[self.myContentView addConstraint:subBar.filterListView.topConstraint];
```

self.myContentView is a UIView that takes up the whole self.view:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[contentView]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView)]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView]|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView)]];
```

To animate the the subBar.filterListView, i remove the top and bottom constrain, reassign them, add them, and animate:

```
[self.myContentView removeConstraint:view.topConstraint];
[self.myContentView removeConstraint:view.bottomConstraint];

view.topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:self.topToolBar
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                 multiplier:1
                                                   constant:0];

view.bottomConstraint.constant -= SUB_BAR_SIZE.height;

[self.myContentView addConstraint:view.topConstraint];
[self.myContentView addConstraint:view.bottomConstraint];

[self.myContentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
    [self.myContentView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Is the code getting confused with top and bottom when it rotates? Does it think the portrait top is the landscape's left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. It doesn't fix the above issue, but rather found another way to approach it.

I changed my constraints to the Visual Format Language (VFL) method instead:

```
subBar.filterListView.verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[filtersSubBar][filterListView(0)]" options:0
                                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                                      views:@{@"filterListView": subBar.filterListView, @"filtersSubBar" : subBar.filtersSubBar}];
```

I think the issue was using the attributes `NSLayoutAttributeTop`, `NSLayoutAttributeRight`, etc that was causing the issue.

Autolayout couldn't handle the rotation and trying to use the `NSLayoutAttributeTop` when it should have been changed to `NSLayoutAttributeRight` to express the new orientation. I suppose we could manually change the constraint.

It seems the VFL handles it differently and does not use the attributes?

This feels as if its either a bug or just a shortcoming of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone coming here from google: i had this exception while calling presentView controller in my custom PushSegue:

```
@implementation PushSegue
- (void) perform
{
    UIViewController* fromController = (UIViewController*) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController* toController = (UIViewController*) self.destinationViewController;

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];

    BOOL iPad = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;

    transition.duration = iPad ? 0.5 : 0.3;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;

    switch ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
            break;

        default:
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
            break;
    }

    [fromController.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    [fromController presentViewController:toController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
@end
```

The cause was that for some misunderstanding i had this in my code:

```
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

(it's my first ios app)
You shouldn't perform such a call, so i removed it and everything works now

Answer (score 0):

You're right, Auto Layout doesn't work with animation transforms that affect the alignment rectangle of the UI object.