# iOS error: Assertion failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, transition, presentviewcontroller

I'm getting an error when calling `presentViewController`

It acts as if it would have something to do with constraints but even when I remove all, it still occurs.

The line of code that causes the crash is: `[[self sourceViewController] presentViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO completion:nil];`

Only if the device is landscape, the error will burst, but while calling this line in portrait, everything works well.

The error I get is:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIView _edgeExpressionInContainer:vertical:max:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:2815
```

Keep in mind this is a last line in a segue class.

Edit: so far, it seem's like the error might be in this line: `self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];` in source view controller.
However, this line is crucial for rounding up a view, for design purposes. The whole block of code concerning that is here:

```
[refreshNotes setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin)];
    [[refreshNotes.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:CGRectMake(refreshNotes.bounds.origin.x, 17, refreshNotes.bounds.size.width, refreshNotes.bounds.size.height)];
    [[refreshNotes.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:95.0/255.0 green:49.0/255.0 blue:187.0/255.0 alpha:1]]; // lighter purple so it doesn't appear black

    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Comment: Usually an assertion failure is accompanied by additional text describing the cause.  Was there any such additional text in this case?

Comment: If you look at @kuchumovn answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139909/auto-layout-screen-rotation-and-uiview-animation), which is a solution to the same problem as yours, as an answer to a slightly different question, he says that having *[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];* in his destination VC messes up the segue.

Comment: Hot Licks: No. That's the only thing I get (besides `lldb`)

rdurand: I have this line in my source view controller, however it is necessary for some design. I'll be posting the whole block of code in the answer edit.

Answer (score 0):

rdurand outlined the line of code that was leading to this error. This was `[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];`

I really didn't know what exactly happened, but I changed the bool parameter from NO to YES. The app doesn't crash no more.

Thanks a lot for help.